# The total of rows fetched by Django's ORM filter is_null=True and is_null=False differs from the total of all rows. Why?

Tags: python, django, orm, left-join, mariadb

Without going into details of my project, I think I am just not seeing something very simple here and need some fresh minds to look at it.
So, look at the following queries:

```
>>> p = MartProduct.objects.filter(source_id=2, eans__isnull=True).count()
100
>>> p = MartProduct.objects.filter(source_id=2, eans__isnull=False).count()
50
>>> p = MartProduct.objects.filter(source_id=2).count()
125
```

It is of course not important to know what the model and their fields represent. It is just a matter that the sum of the *is_null=True* and *is_null=False* should match the total number of rows. In other words I would expect the result of the last query to be 150 not 125! If it was the other way around (total number of objects > than the sum of the *is_null=True* and *is_null=False* then I could think of reasons for it but this is just weird).

What can be a cause for this? I can't think of any.
Thanks to anyone who will join this puzzle :)

Comment: If you are joining other models you might have duplicates. Can you add `distinct()` for each query and try again?

Comment: I knew it was something totally stupid. You got it man. Thank you. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as accepted!